# Python CSV Max Min

Tags: python, csv, max, min

how can I find min and max in each column for a file in csv format in Python?

For example, we have some data for cars:

```
Mercedez, 599, 35, 68, 25
BMW, 7777777, 45, 88, 75
Audi, 646463626, 64, 10, 0
Toyota, 38383838833838, -1, 9, 5
```

The result is:

```
 ,38383838833838,64,88,75 #max
 ,599,-1,9,0 #min
```

Thanks for any advice)

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far, instead of us simply doing it for you?

Answer (score 0):

use pandas (pip install pandas in command line):

```
import pandas as pd
cardata = pd.read_csv(path)
cardata.min()
cardata.max()
```

where path is the path to the csv file or just the filename if its in the same directory (dont forget the .csv)

Answer (score 0):

You should really post code instead of us doing it for you but here goes...

```
def MinMax(File):
    Min = []
    Max = []
    File = open(File)
    for Line in File:
        Line = (Line.strip()).split(", ")
        for Index, Value in enumerate(Line):
            try:
                
                try:
                    Value = int(Value)
                    if Value < Min[Index]:
                        Min[Index] = Value
                    if Value > Max[Index]:
                        Max[Index] = Value
                except ValueError:
                    Min[Index] = None
                    Max[Index] = None

            except IndexError:
                Min.append(Value)
                Max.append(Value)
    return Min, Max

File = "Test.csv"

Min, Max = MinMax(File)
```

Not the prettiest solution but will return:

```
Min = [None, 599, -1, 9, 0]
Max = [None, 38383838833838, 64, 88, 75]
```

which is what you wanted?